# Get Current Applied Image Style Name

Tags: 8, hooks

How do you get the currently chosen image style name from the field format display option?

I can load an image with a given style with the code below, however, the style name (e.g. thumbnail) is hard-coded.

```
$imageStyle = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('image_style')
  ->load('thumbnail');
```

I am hoping to get the selected style name dynamically.

**MYMODULE.module**:

```
HOOK_preprocess_menu() {

  $imagePath = getUser()['currentUser']->$imageFieldName
    ->entity->uri->value;

  $imageStyleFormatterValue = ???;

  $imageStyle = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('image_style')
    ->load($imageStyleFormatterValue);

  $imageStyleURL = $imageStyle
    ->buildUrl($imagePath);

  $markup = new TranslatableMarkup(
    '<span style="background-image: url(@imageStyleURL);"></span>', [
      '@imageStyleURL' => $imageStyleURL,
    ]
  );

}
```

For my case, `$imageStyleURL` will be printed as `background-image: url();`, so I need to build the path in preprocess.

I've tried going through `FieldConfig`, `->entity`, and `FieldStorage`, but cannot find the image style value stored anywhere.

Comment: It's hard to tell by this small code snippet. Normally it is the job of the field formatter to get the formatter options as input and produce the field output. See for example [Simple Background image formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/background_image_formatter)

Comment: Thanks, @4k4, I've added a little more context to my question. I will look at that module but hoping not to have any dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field format display options are components of view modes, stored in the config entity `EntityViewDisplay`.

For example, load the `default` view mode for the user and extract the configured image style of the `user_picture` field:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay;

  $component = EntityViewDisplay::load('user.user.default')->getComponent('user_picture');
  $image_style = $component['settings']['image_style'];
```